# Google Translate API in a .NET Windows Application

Tags: .net, google-translate

I have a .NET windows application which uses the Google Translate API. When trying to translate strings today i got a "Terms of Abuse" exception. To use a google API effectively, it is recommended that you register for a key which should resolve this problem. My translate API does not use a key. However to use a key,the site states that we would need to enter a valid URL of ours - e.g. http://localhost etc. However this one is a windows application. How do i get a valid key?

Comment: Sounds like you need to talk to Google on this one.  "Terms of Abuse" pretty much says it all.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with google API (geocoding and maps) and the key really doesn't matter. I entered any key and it did fine.

Comment: I would check the Terms and Conditions very carefully if taking this approach, particularly if you are working on a commercial application.  Just because you can technically achieve something doesn't mean you should do or have a right to!

Answer (score 0):

From the [Google Translate 'Getting Started'](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html) guide:

> Important: The Google Translate API requires the use of an API key, which you can get from the Google APIs console.

That page has a link to instructions to get a key.

Comment: Hi,Yes but mine is a windows application which uses the google api. I do not have a url to specify to get a key. I tried giving a dummy url and did get a key, it worked fine for a couple of runs and then the key became void/invalid.